# Show that the transformation T defined by T(x1,x2)...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the transformation $T$ defined by $T(x_1, x_2) = (2|x_2|, 3x_1 - x_2)$ is **not** linear.

How can I do this? I know that if

$T(cu + dv) = cT(u) + dT(v) \implies $ $T$ **is** a linear transformation. I'm not sure how to actually apply this formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $T$ is linear we have in particular $T(-x)=-T(x)$. In our case we have $T(-(0,1))=(2,1)=T((0,1))$. So our transformation is not linear.

Comment: where does 0 and 1 come from??

Comment: like i don't understand how you all use this formula and pluig in what they gave

Comment: I took an arbitrary vector and tested the linearity. I chose a vector such that $x_2\neq 0$

Comment: @Shammy It is a specific example of a vector $x$ such that $T(-x) \neq -T(x)$. This means that $T$ is not linear. Not all vectors will create a counterexample like this, but $(0,1)$ does.

Comment: i just dont understand how u knew to pick 0,1

Comment: I could have picked almost any vector such that $x_2\neq 0$. I took this one to have the simplest computations

Comment: ok youre saying that $x_1 =0, x_2 = 1$ right??

Comment: You 're spot on

Comment: because in that casse $T-(0,1) = (-2,1)$ not $T(0,1)$ ?

Comment: No $2|x_2|=2$ and not $-2$

Comment: oh wow, yup, im an idiot

Comment: so i can pick any number as long as $x_2 \ne 0$ ?

Comment: Here's the general idea, Shammy: if you're trying to prove something is *true*, you have to show that it's true for all cases.  But if you're trying to prove something is *false*, you only have to show that it fails in one case.  Pick any $(x_1,x_2)$ where $T$ fails to have the property of homogeneity (this part of linearity: $T(kv) = kT(v)$) and you've shown that $T$ is not linear.

Comment: This is extremely confusing. if $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1$ then $T-(0,1) = T(0,-1) = (2(1), 0 - -1) = (2,1)$ but then $-T(0,1) = (2(1), 0 - 1) = -T(2,-1) = T(-2,1) \implies$ not linear?

Comment: @Shammy If $T$ were linear then $T[-(0,1)]$ would equal $-T(0,1)$.  If that's not the case then $T$ is not linear.

Comment: So dumb question, but in the first case you just provided @Bye_World we get $(2,1)$ in the second case, do we just apply the negative after we have computed the inside so then we would get $(-2,1)$ which would show that they don't equal and that it is not linear?

Comment: Yep.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $T$ is linear, then $T(x)=-T(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

For every vector in $\mathbb R^2$, $u$ and $v$, we have:
$$u = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ and 
$$v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then for two scalars $c$ and $d$:
$$cu+dv =  \begin{bmatrix} cu_1+dv_1 \\ cu_2+dv_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
the transformation of this vector by **T** is:
$$\mathbf T(cu+dv) =  \begin{bmatrix} 2\lvert cu_2+dv_2 \rvert \\ 3(cu_1+dv_1) \end{bmatrix}$$
which cannot be written as 
$$c \begin{bmatrix} 2 \lvert u_2 \rvert \\ 3u_1-u_2 \end{bmatrix}+d  \begin{bmatrix} 2\lvert v_2\rvert \\ 3u_1-v_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
So **T** is not *linear*

**NOTE**: this  method combines the two properties in a single one, you can split them seperately to check them one by one:

- $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v) \quad u, \, v $ are vectors
- $T(cu) = c T(u)$,   c is a scalar